# ¿cómo mostrar en el frontend una imagen que es un custom field de un custom post type en wordpress?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, wordpress

Intento recuperar la imagen con get_post_meta, pero el valor que me devuelve es por ejemplo:
https://mi-sitio.net/cpt/cpt-en-turno/406/

Cuando en realidad debería ser:
https://mi-sitio.net/uploads/mi_imagen.png/

En mi sitio sólo aparece el ícono de la imagen rota. Cuando le doy con el clic derecho la opción de Ver imagen en otra pestaña, es cuando me aparece la dirección
https://mi-sitio.net/cpt/cpt-en-turno/406/

En el Back-End la imagen se muestra correctamente en la biblioteca de medios, pero no puedo hacer que se vea en el front-end. Tal vez get_post_meta() no sea la función adecuada.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: `get_post_meta( $post_ID, $meta_key )`  debería funcionar con cualquier post type, salvo que sea una taxonomía ahí se usa `get_term_meta( $term_id, $meta_key )` . el CTP y el custom field los definis por código? si son por plugin cada uno tiene su set de funciones que ayudan

Comment: Utilizo el plugin ACF para crear los Custom Fields, y yo desarrollé el código para crear el CPT. El código es así: 

`<?php
$huella  = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'huella', true);
?>

<img src="<?php print $huella; ?>" />`

Comment: ACF puede llegar a generar un alias para el field, probá con [`get_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) ( lo mismo sucede a veces con `update_post_meta()` y `update_field()` ) . Para detectar si ACF está activo y se puede dar esa situación podes usar `if( ! class_exists('ACF') ) :`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda alo Malbarez, desconozco el motivo por el que get_field no me funcionó, pero sí me funcionó wp_get_attachment_url()
Gracias de nuevo

Comment: será que te está devolviendo el id (406) del attachment en vez de la url, si es eso se configura en el custom field ( id, array, object, url, etc.. ) hay varios ejemplos en https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/ incluido el de usar `wp_get_attachment_image()` que genera un set para [responsives](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/)